# Flutterで作ったAndroidアプリをリリース版とデバッグ版で別々に動かす方法

Tags: android, flutter

アプリのリリース版を実機に入れてテストしてるのですが、ここでAndroid Studioから実機に（`--debug`をつけて）実行すると、（おそらくアプリケーションIDが同じなため）エラーとなりアプリが消えてしまいます。app\build.gradleに

```
    buildTypes {
        debug{
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
```

を追加するとアプリケーションIDが<アプリID>.debugになるのですが、google-services.jsonのアプリIDと異なってしまうためやはりエラーが起きます。エラーを起こさないためにはいちいち手作業でgoogle-services.jsonのpackage_nameを変えなければいけません。
どうしたら自動でデバッグモードで実行することができるでしょう？

Comment: デバッグの際、実機にインストールされているのはリリース版、デバッグ版のどちらですか？

Comment: リリース版です。

Answer (score 0):

未検証ですが、`android/app/src/debug`ディレクトリに
`package_name`を変えた`google-services.json`のコピーを配置する方法はどうでしょうか。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609868/android-buildtypes-applicationidsuffix-error

ちなみに私の場合、`Flavor`を用意して分けるようにしています。
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors